# How to place the text on the specific position?

Tags: python, pygame

I stuck on the point on how to place the text on the specific coordinates (resizable window and picture on the background is included). Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import threading, os, sys, time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("AI Battlehip Game")

original_size = (1200,700)

FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(original_size, HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
back_end_image_set = pygame.image.load(r'/Users/User1/Desktop/Project work/images/backgroundimage1.jpg') 
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(back_end_image_set, original_size), (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()


myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 60)
label = myFont.render('Check 1', 1, (red))

pos_W = (1200 - label.get_width())//2
pos_H = (700 - label.get_height())//2

FPS.tick(60)

try:                                                   
    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
        elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
            new_size = event.dict['size']
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(back_end_image_set, new_size), (0,0))
            label_W = pos_W * new_size[0] // original_size[0]
            label_H = pos_H * new_size[1] // original_size[1] 
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(label, (label_W, label_H)), (0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()
except:
    raise
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to scale the position and the size of text surface (`label`):

```py
label_W = label.get_width() * new_size[0] // original_size[0]
label_H = label.get_height() * new_size[1] // original_size[1]
label_X = pos_W * new_size[0] // original_size[0]
label_Y = pos_H * new_size[1] // original_size[1] 
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(label, (label_W, label_H)), (label_X, label_Y))
```

Note, resizing linear scales the window along the x and y axis. The scale factors for the x and y axis can be applied to each point or vector on the surface. The position of a rectangle changes in the same scale as its size:

```py
scale_x, scale_y = (new_size[0] / original_size[0], new_size[1] / original_size[1])

label_size = (int(label.get_width() * scale_x), int(label.get_height() * scale_y))
label_pos  = (int(pos_W             * scale_x), int(pos_H              * scale_y))

screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(label, label_size), label_pos)
```